# WkWebview - manage the subresources download

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

In our app html content is loaded into wkwebview. The html has lot of sub resources like images,twitter,instagram and beacon urls.

I want to capture the requests and fetch them using custom  network class so that I can manage the requests based on network type. Incase of 2G we want to have fewer concurrent requests compared to 3G and 4G.

Is this possible?

Comment: Any leads will be helpful

Comment: I am interested in the solution. Please update if you find a way to do this

Comment: Looks like this might not be possible due to wkwebview implementation. It performs work out-of-process  https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/21956

Comment: this is not good to hear...